# How to enable unicode when compiling using cl.exe from Visual Studio Build Tools?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, cl

I'm trying to have unicode characters in WIN32 (winapi, no console) program compiled using cl.exe from Visual Studio Build Tools. I've defined UNICODE and _UNICODE in my program source and also using cmd option, but I still don't get unicode characters. Here is my compilation command line: `cl C:\path_to_source\preventShutdown.c kernel32.lib user32.lib /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /O2 /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:wWinMain` and my source code:

```c
/*
cl C:\path_to_source\preventShutdown.c kernel32.lib user32.lib /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /O2 /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:wWinMain
*/
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPWSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
LPCTSTR windowClassName=TEXT("windowClass"),windowName=TEXT("Zatrzymaj wyłączenie");
WNDCLASS windowClass={0};
windowClass.hInstance=hInstance;
windowClass.hIcon=NULL;
windowClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
windowClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
windowClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
windowClass.lpszClassName=windowClassName;
windowClass.lpfnWndProc=&WindowProc;
if(!RegisterClass(&windowClass))return -1;
HWND hWnd=NULL;
if(!(hWnd=CreateWindow(windowClassName,windowName,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)))return -2;
MSG msg={0};
int bRet=0;
while((bRet=GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))!=0)
{
 if(-1==bRet)return -3;
 TranslateMessage(&msg);
 DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
ExitProcess((UINT)msg.wParam);
return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage(0);
break;
case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWnd,TEXT("Rozpoczęto przez użytkownika"));
break;
case WM_ENDSESSION:
return 0;
break;
default:
return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
break;
}
return 0;
}
```

- where path_to_source is real path to source code.

Comment: First of all you should indent your code.

Comment: Clearly the text editor is feeble at handling C++ source code, good odds that the compiler won't correctly parse a string literal like "wyłączenie".  Use one that can save a text file with a BOM, or use the /utf-8 compile option.

Comment: Your code shows accented characters in the title when I run it.  Why do you say it doesn't support Unicode?

Comment: @Julian "*I still don't get unicode characters*" - meaning WHAT, exactly?  WHERE are you not getting Unicode characters where you are expecting?

Comment: Since you have named your entry point `wWinMain` and don't get linker errors, everything is properly configured to use Unicode as the ambient character set. The issue is somewhere else, likely what Hans Passant noted: You're going to have to save your **source** code using UTF-8.

Comment: Just noticed, you are explicitly setting the `/ENTRY`-point. This is very likely not what you want to do. For one, it has the [wrong signature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573). Are you sure you understand the consequences of not linking against the language support libraries? There are several paths through your `wWinMain` implementation that fail to terminate the process.

Comment: @IInspectable in what situations exacly. it fails to terminate the process?

Comment: The process doesn't terminate when `ExitProcess` isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Hans Passant stated it the comment, problem was that compiler doesn't recognize my source file as unicode. Saving a file with BOM or adding `/source-charset:utf-8` option makes it work correctly. I prefer the second option:  `cl /source-charset:utf-8 C:\path_to_source\preventShutdown.c kernel32.lib user32.lib /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /O2 /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:wWinMain`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Unicode stuff, then just use Unicode stuff directly (`WCHAR` strings, `W`-based APIs, etc). Stay away from all that `TCHAR` stuff based on `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` altogether, this is not the 1990's anymore.  There is no need to rely on `TCHAR` anymore (unless you need to support Win9x/ME).

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    LPCWSTR windowClassName = L"windowClass", windowName = L"Zatrzymaj wyłączenie";
    WNDCLASSW windowClass = {0};
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = NULL;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = windowClassName;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&windowClass)) return -1;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(windowClassName, windowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) return -2;

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWnd, L"Rozpoczęto przez użytkownika");
            break;
        case WM_ENDSESSION:
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is the problem?  Does TCHAR not work anymore?

Comment: @stark it does, when used properly.  But Windows is a Unicode OS, all of the ANSI APIs were deprecated a LONG time ago.  Unless you need to support Win9x/ME, there is no reason to deal with `TCHAR` anymore.  It is just one less obstacle to deal with.

Comment: The ANSI APIs are not deprecated - in fact you can use them with UTF-8 and it may become the recommended way to do things:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page

> Until recently, Windows has emphasized "Unicode" -W variants over -A APIs. However, recent releases have used the ANSI code page and -A APIs as a means to introduce UTF-8 support to apps. If the ANSI code page is configured for UTF-8, then -A APIs typically operate in UTF-8. This model has the benefit of supporting existing code built with -A APIs without any code changes.